# How can I make it so python reads a file, and the task is for someone to name 10 songs from this file, without being able to repeat a song

Tags: python

In python, I am trying to make it so python reads a text file (this text file has a list of songs, all on different lines) , and the person running the code needs to name 10 of these songs. I have managed to do this mostly, however it allows you to put the same answer for all 10 guesses. Can anyone help, so you cannot say the same answer?

```
import random
score = 0
print("Welcome to my quiz. The task is to name 10 of Juice Wrld's songs. You get two wrong answers, and if you pass that margin you lose. Good luck!")
    
def login(): #defines the function
    file = open("musicpass.txt", "r")
    password = file.read()
    userguess = input("Enter password for access: ")
    if password == userguess:
        print("Access Granted!")
        game(song)
        ransong()
    else:
        print("Access Denied!")
        login()

def ransong():
    with open("musicsongs.txt", "r") as file:
        content= file.read()
        words = content.splitlines()
  
    # print random string
    #print(random.choice(words))
    return words


def game(song):
    songlist = song
    guess=0
    score=0
    while guess != 2:
        if score == 10:
            print("Well done, you win!")
            break
            
        usguess1 = input("Enter your choice here: ")
        if usguess1 in songlist:
            print("Correct!")
            score = score + 1                                             
        else:
            print("Incorrect, one more guess allowed")
            guess = guess + 1
    else:
        print("Your score is:",score)
        print("Incorrect, no more guesses left.")



def main():
    login()
song=ransong()
main()
```

Comment: p.s.  making song a global variable is bad practice,  you could just call songlist= ransong() inside game()

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the song from the list like this after they guess correctly:

```
if usguess1 in songlist:
    songlist.remove(usguess1)
    print("Correct!")
    score = score + 1
```

Or build a list of guesses and check against that, if you want to do something different for duplicates

```
guesses=[]
if usguess1 in songlist:
    if usguess1 in guesses:
        print("Already Guessed!")
    else:
        print("Correct!")
        score = score + 1
```